# Make Manipulate display color buttons

Tags: graphics

The following code ends up showing a set of buttons for the variables color one and colortwo and the label of each is the RGBColor primitive for the corresponding color (this is only true in version 9, versions 10 and 11 display color buttons without text). I would like to display each button in the corresponding color itself and its label to be the name of the color. Thanks.

```
Manipulate[Show@Graphics[{
    colorone,
    Polygon[{
      {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, .7}
      }],
    colortwo, Opacity[.5],
    Polygon[{
      {0, 0}, RotationMatrix[x].{1, 0}, RotationMatrix[x].{.5 , .7}
      }]
    }, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
 {{x, Pi .4}, 0, 2 Pi},
 {colorone, {Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Purple}},
 {colortwo, {Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple, Red}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/drCfb.png -- What version are you using?

Comment: Try ``SetSystemOptions["TypesetOptions" -> "ColorDirectiveSwatches" -> True]``

Comment: What is the output of `SystemOptions["TypesetOptions"]`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the apparent error is not reproducible and likely the result of a faulty kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works as you intended in v10.4.1 and 11.0.1. For an earlier version,

```
$Version

(*  "9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)"  *)

Manipulate[
 Show@
  Graphics[
   {colorone, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, .7}}],
    colortwo, Opacity[.5],
    Polygon[{{0, 0},
      RotationMatrix[x].{1, 0},
      RotationMatrix[x].{.5, .7}}]},
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
 {{x, Pi .4}, 0, 2 Pi},
 {{colorone, Red},
  (# -> Graphics[{#, Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.15]]}]) & /@
   {Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Purple}},
 {{colortwo, Yellow},
  (# -> Graphics[{#, Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.15]]}]) & /@
   {Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple, Red}}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

To add `Text`

```
Manipulate[
 Show@
  Graphics[
   {colorone, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, .7}}],
    colortwo, Opacity[.5], 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, RotationMatrix[x].{1, 0}, RotationMatrix[x].{.5, .7}}]},
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
 {{x, Pi .4}, 0, 2 Pi},
 {{colorone, Red, "Color One"},
  (ToExpression[#] -> Graphics[{ToExpression[#],
        Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.15]],
        Text[ToString[#], Scaled[{0.5, 0.1}]]}]) & /@
   {"Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Purple"}},
 {{colortwo, Yellow, "Color Two"},
  (ToExpression[#] -> Graphics[{ToExpression[#],
        Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.15]],
        Text[ToString[#], Scaled[{0.5, 0.1}]]}]) & /@
   {"Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Red"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ya, I have 9 on my laptop, sry.